# Node / JS promises blocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, closures, edge.js

New to Node/JS and I'm creating a password recovery page for an exiting IT portal, it searches AD(ldap) and a DB where the user has registered. Based on the results from both presents user with options to auth then change pwd

When I make a request ($get()) from the client to find a user the backend stalls intermittently. See console logging below

This is the console logging

```
Attempting to find : <account name>
Found AD user: <account name>
in acc prep
in sql request
in getUserRegistration //within auth controller

.
.here it prints the results of the sql query // At this point I would expect the promise to be fulfilled.
.
```

This is where time is spent doing who knows what. It eventually completes but usually takes minutes. then prints...

```
in sql results
```

The stall seems to be after calling **return auth.getUserRegistration(globalUser.sql)** from within a then(). The logging from the auth controller very quickly logs the results from the sql query which is right before it should be resolved, thereby returning the results to the following then(). So i don't believe there to be a issue with the auth controller (which independently works flawlessly) but rather within the resolve(). Perhaps because its within a another promise?.

What I find Interesting and confuses me is if I browse to the portal from another tab/browser the backend work completes and the page renders immediately.

See code below

```
/* Client request */

$.get(urlqry, function(result) {
  if (result.match("<div id=\"pop\">")) {

    $.modal(result, {
        onClose: function () {
          $("[id^=simplemodal").remove();
          $("#findload").hide();
          $("#forgetbtn").show();
          $.modal.close();
      }
    });

  } else {
    console.log("in else");
    $("#divid").html(result)
  }

});

/* 
this is the route that renders based the work from 2 different controllers
1. check if user exists in Active Directory (ldap)
2. check if user has registered (sql)
*/

router.get('/forgetpwd', function(req, res) {

  var usrname = req.query.usr
  var domain = req.query.realm

  if (usrname && domain) {

    console.log("Attempting to find : " + usrname + "@" + domain);

    var globalUser = {
      username: "",
      upn: "",
      accounts: [],
      sql: {},
      registered: false
    }

    ad.getUser(usrname, domain)

    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.userPrincipalName) {

        console.log("Found AD user: " + result.userPrincipalName);

        globalUser.username = result.sAMAccountName
        globalUser.upn = result.userPrincipalName
        globalUser.accounts = result.extensionAttribute15

      } else {

        var fail = {
          status: "fail",
          message: "Unknown Error"
        }

        var msg = result ? result : fail

        throw msg;

      }

    })

    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("in acc prep");

        globalUser.sql.username = globalUser.username
        var upns = globalUser.accounts

        if (upns) {
          upns = upns.split(",")

          for (u in upns) {

            var upn = upns[u].split("@")
            var domain = upn.slice(-1)[0].toLowerCase()

            switch (domain) {
              case "domain1":
                globalUser.sql.domain1UPN = upns[u]
                break;
              case "domain2":
                globalUser.sql.domain2UPN = upns[u]
                break;
              case "domain3":
                globalUser.sql.ihUPN = upns[u]
                break;
              default:
                globalUser.accounts = ""
                break;
            }
          }
        } else {
          globalUser.accounts = ""
        }
        return;

      })

    .then(function(result) {
      console.log("in sql request");

      return auth.getUserRegistration(globalUser.sql)

    })

    .then(function(result) {

      console.log("in sql results");

      if (result.length > 0) {

        globalUser.registered = true
        return

      } else {

        globalUser.registered = false
        return

      }

    })

    .then(function(result) {

      var accounts = {
        username: globalUser.username,
        accounts: globalUser.accounts.split(","),
        registered: globalUser.registered

      }

      console.log(accounts);
      res.render('./forget-options', accounts);

    })

    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("in catch");
      var failure = {
        status: "fail",
        message: error

      }
      console.log(failure);
      res.render("./ack", failure);
      return

    })

  } else {

    console.log("User field empty and/or Domaim no selected");

  }
});

/*
Checks if a a record exist in a DB based on results from ad.getUser
requires edge/edge-sql
*/

auth.getUserRegistration = function(accounts) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var query = "select * from [users] where (username = "
    query += "\'" + accounts.username + "\'"
    if (accounts.domain2UPN) {
      query += " or domain2UPN = \'" + accounts.domain2UPN + "\'"
    }
    if (accounts.domain1UPN) {
      query += " or domain1UPN = \'" + accounts.domain1UPN + "\'"
    }

    query += ") and q1col is not null and q2col is not null and pin is not null;"

    var sqlparams = {
      connectionString: "Data Source=name.domain.com;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True",
      source: query
    };

    var getReg = edge.func('sql', sqlparams);

    getReg(null, function(error, result) {

      if (error) {

        console.log("Retrieving user ?? registration");
        reject(error);

      } else {

        console.log("in getUserRegistration");
        console.log(result);
        resolve(result);

      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you add a time to every log statement and probably add a few more log statements to track progress in more detail and then you can see exactly where the time is being taken when it happens.

Comment: It's a little unusual to use `.then()` handlers purely for blocks of synchronous code.  Though that isn't the cause of your long delay, this does not help your execution speed.

Comment: Hi jfrend, I actually have, i stripped down a wack of debugging lines because they provided no value. there is nothing between return auth.getUserRegistration(globalUser.sql) and the following then(). Everything else returns and logs as expected. Any particular place you can recommend logging? I can add time but i fear they will only return what i already know

Comment: I'm guessing your referring to the then()'s that contain "console.log("in acc prep")" and "console.log("in sql results")"? I moved them out to help debug and plan on moving them back once i get this figured out.

Comment: If you already know exactly which operation stalls for minutes, then please add that information to the question - that was not clear to me when reading the question.  And, I'd suggest you share exactly what the SQL statement is when it stalls.  Also, is there potentially more than one thread accessing your database?  Could your database be in the middle of some administrative maintenance operation?

Comment: Any chance your SQL database is on a hard drive that powers itself down for energy saving reasons and isn't used for other things such that there would be a long delay every once in awhile to power up the hard drive?

Comment: I've updated the post, hope it makes more sense. Its not the MS SQL either because the not only are other apps running off it but plus the controllers function works by itself

Comment: You seem to imply you think this is a problem with the promise infrastructure or a problem with `resolve()`.  I've never seen such a problem and it seems unlikely that promises could introduce a multi-minute delay.  They just set some state and schedule the `.then()` handlers to run on the next tick.  So unless you have something else running in this JS process that interferes with when a `nextTick()` can run, it's hard to see how this could be a problem with promises.

Comment: To be honest I don't have enough knowledge or experience to infer anything, I'm just at a complete loss. What do you make of browsing to the site from another client resolving it on the initial client? Also if i hit refresh from the existing page the back end work completes immediately.

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of concurrency problem in your server if one request is affecting another request that dramatically.  I don't see such a problem in the code you've disclosed, but that code calls a lot of other functions whose code you haven't included so we can't examine.  A multi-minute delay that isn't explainable by a very complicated time consuming back-end operation is typically some sort of communications issue or lock contention issue that eventually times out.

Comment: Is there any additional code that I could post that may be of use? Or any suggestions on how to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Like I said earlier, you need to figure out exactly where the delay is at this level and then instrument down into the function that has the delay until you find the exact lowest level async operation that causes the delay.  This is an incremental debugging problem.  It shouldn't take too long if you can reproduce the problem upon demand.  If it's not easily reproducible, then you have instrument the hell out of things so when it occurs you can then diagnose the logs, learn from that and then instrument some more if you didn't get the final answer yet.

Comment: If you isolate exactly which lower level function the problem is occurring in then you can add the code to that function.  With this level of information, it's pretty hard for us to find the problem with code inspection.  You need a lot more instrumentation detail to narrow down which piece of code is causing the problem and then we can help you examine that code.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, I updated my post with resolution. I appreciate your time

Comment: You aren't supposed to put the answer into your question.  Instead file your own answer and accept it.  You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my db module from edge-sql to mssql and updated my code accordingly. It worked immediately.

```
auth.getUserRegistration = function(accounts) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var query = "select * from [users] where (username = "
    query += "\'" + accounts.username + "\'"
    if (accounts.domain2UPN) {
      query += " or domain2UPN = \'" + accounts.domain2UPN + "\'"
    }
    if (accounts.domain1UPN) {
      query += " or domain1UPN = \'" + accounts.domain1UPN + "\'"
    }

    query += ") and q1col is not null and q2col is not null and pin is not null;"

    sql.connect("mssql://<usr>:<pwd>@<server>/<db>").then(function() {         
        new sql.Request().query(query).then(function(recordset) {
            console.log(recordset);
            resolve(recordset);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
  });
}
```